# How do I select xml element attributes using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

Ok, I have this code for the stored procedure right now.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Readxml]
@xmlparam XML
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @CustomerXml AS XML
SET @CustomerXml = @xmlparam

INSERT INTO Custtable.dbo.SPCustomer
(
    CustomerId,
    CustomerName
)
SELECT 
    Customer.attribute.value('CustomerId[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS CustomerId,
    Customer.attribute.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS CustomerName
FROM 
    @xmlparam.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS Customer(attribute)
END
```

My XML looks like this (simplified).

```
<Customers>
  <Customer CustomerId="94" Name="name1" />
  <Customer CustomerId="95" Name="name2" />
  <Customer CustomerId="96" Name="name3" />
</Customers>
```

With my code right now I am not able to get the attribute values, as I understand I am trying to get elements inside the `<Customer>` tag, called `CustomerId` and `Name`, that don't exist.

When selecting all rows from the table, after the procedure is done, I get all the rows but with NULL values.

My question, how do I get the attributes from the XML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.attribute.value('@CustomerId', 'nvarchar(255)') AS CustomerId,
    Customer.attribute.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(255)') AS CustomerName
FROM 
    @xmlparam.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS Customer(attribute)
```

To get the attribute, use a leading `@`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect, I'll accept you answer after the eight minutes rule!

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Readxml]
@xmlparam XML
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @CustomerXml AS XML
SET @CustomerXml = @xmlparam

INSERT INTO Custtable.dbo.SPCustomer
(
    CustomerId,
    CustomerName
)
SELECT Customer.attribute.value('@CustomerId', 'BIGINT') AS CustomerId,
    Customer.attribute.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(255)') AS CustomerName
FROM @xmlparam.nodes('Customers/Customer') AS Customer(attribute)

END
```

Comment: Dont't know who was first but saw marc_s first. Thanks for the answer!